# Find if rows in a large file contain a substring from a seperate list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large (30GB) file consisting of random terms and sentences. I have two separate lists of words and phrases I want to apply to that and mark (or alternatively filter) a row in which a term for that list appears.

If a term from list X appears in a row of the large file, mark it X, if from list Y, mark it Y. When done, take the rows marked X and output it to a file, same for Y as a separate file. My problem is that both of my lists are 1500 terms long and take a while to go through line by line.

After fidgeting around a while, I've arrived on my current method which filters the chunks on whether it contains a term. My issue is that it is very slow. I am wondering if there is a way to speed up my script to get through it faster? I was using Pandas to process the file in chunks of 1 million rows, it takes around 3 minutes to process a chunk with my current method:

```
white_text_file = open('lists/health_whitelist_final.txt', "r")

white_list = white_text_file.read().split(',\n')

black_text_file = open('lists/health_blacklist_final.txt', "r")

black_list = black_text_file.read().split(',\n')

for chunk in pd.read_csv('final_cleaned_corpus.csv', chunksize=chunksize, names=['Keyword']):

    print("Chunk")

    chunk_y = chunk[chunk['Keyword'].str.contains('|'.join(white_list), na=False)]

    chunk_y.to_csv(VERTICAL+'_y_list.csv', mode='a', header=None)

    chunk_x = chunk[chunk['Keyword'].str.contains('|'.join(black_list), na=False)]

    chunk_x.to_csv(VERTICAL+'_x_list.csv', mode='a', header=None)
```

My first attempt was less pythonic but the aim was to break the loop the first time an element appears, this way was slower that my current one:

```
def x_or_y(keyword):

    #print(keyword)

    iden = ''

    for item in y_list:

        if item in keyword:

            iden = 'Y'
            break

    for item in x_list:

        if item in keyword:

            iden = 'X'
            break

    return iden
```

Is there a faster way I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to do the following:

```
fileContent = ['yes','foo','junk','yes','foo','junk']

x_list = ['yes','no','maybe-so']
y_list = ['foo','bar','fizzbuzz']

def x_or_y(keyword):
  if keyword in x_list:
    return 'X'
  if keyword in y_list:
    return 'Y'
  return ''

results = map(x_or_y, fileContent)

print(list(results))
```

Here is an example: https://repl.it/F566